# Kanji reading of a name

Tags: kanji, readings, names

What reading would be used for "鮫" if it's a last name or a first name?

Answer (score 3):

Well according to [here](http://www2s.biglobe.ne.jp/~suzakihp/index40.html) there are 2 households with the last name 鮫{さめ} in Japan. Perhaps you met one of them? :)

However, if you change it to 鮫島{さめじま/さめしま} you can find many more households, like this women's soccer player:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aya_Sameshima